# $state is not defined. Error on entity page generated by jhipster version 4

Tags: angularjs, pagination, jhipster

When I try to change **page** using **pagination bar** in an entity generated by Jhipster, get the following javascript error: **$state is not defined**

I am evaluating the **JHipster version 4.0.5** framework with angularJS version 1 to clientFramework. All entities were generated through the command **jhipster:entity *entity-name*** using **pagination** option.

The problem is on the *entitycontroller.js* generated 'state' variable is missing on the controller injection. e.g.

```
 EntityController.$inject = ['Entity', 'ParseLinks', 'AlertService', 'paginationConstants','$state']
```

Can you solve this issue for the next release?

Comment: This should be created in issues section of the corresponding repository: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify *_entity-management.controller.js*

This file is located on the directory:
**../node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/entity/templates/client/angularjs/src/main/webapp/app/entities/_entity-management.controller.js**

You need to add **$state** variable on the $inject and function code. Here you have, the changed code for jhipster 4.0.5 release:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('<%=angularAppName%>')
        .controller('<%= entityAngularName %>Controller', <%= entityAngularName %>Controller);

    <%= entityAngularName %>Controller.$inject = [<% if (fieldsContainBlob) { %>'DataUtils', <% } %>'<%= entityClass %>'<% if (searchEngine == 'elasticsearch') { %>, '<%= entityClass %>Search'<% } %><% if (pagination != 'no') { %>, 'ParseLinks', 'AlertService', 'paginationConstants', '$state'<% } %> <%_ if (pagination == 'pager' || pagination == 'pagination'){ %>, 'pagingParams'<% } %>];

    function <%= entityAngularName %>Controller(<% if (fieldsContainBlob) { %>DataUtils, <% } %><%= entityClass %><% if (searchEngine == 'elasticsearch') { %>, <%= entityClass %>Search<% } %><% if (pagination != 'no') { %>, ParseLinks, AlertService, paginationConstants, $state<% } %> <%_ if (pagination == 'pager' || pagination == 'pagination'){ %>, pagingParams<% } %>) {

        var vm = this;

        <%_ if (pagination == 'pagination' || pagination == 'pager') { _%>
<%- include('pagination-template'); -%>
        <%_ } else if (pagination == 'infinite-scroll') { _%>
<%- include('infinite-scroll-template'); -%>
        <%_ } else { _%>
<%- include('no-pagination-template'); -%>
        <%_ } _%>
    }
})();
```

I hope it is useful.